# Why emulator in Android Studio not associated with project even after it is showing in AVD List?

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

I have successfully created sample flutter project. Also, emulator has been created with following configuration:

[image: AVD Description]

After loading project, I am able to see my emulator in AVD List.

[image: Issue Details]

But when I try to associate emulator with sample project,it only starts the emulator but I am not able to run my sample project.

Please help to solve the respective issue as I am new to Flutter Development.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you selecting the right module?

Comment: Pardon me but could you please elaborate about which module you are asking?

Comment: What happens when you press the play button ?

Comment: A message is displayed - "No connected devices has been found". But I have already created emulator.